# How to uninstall nodejs (recent method) on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a recent method to completely uninstall nodejs. Is there any command? Any easy method?
I'm not looking for uninstaller scripts as I want to learn the process.

Using nodejs 0.12 on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed different kinds of nodejs like  me.

try any of this below to remove what you have installed.

```
// this will remove node
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove node

// this will remove nodejs-legacy
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs-legacy

// this will remove nodejs
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
```

I didn't know what I have installed because of too many tries. until uninstalling nodejs was a success.